# Can't understand notation of formula

Tags: notation

The notation in the image features a straight line after the first fraction with some sort of parameter (?) given below. What does this mean in English exactly?

[image: Equation]

Comment: I'd read it as " evaluated at " $VBE=0$ and I'd guess something to do with electronics current / voltage.

Comment: So the equasion performed with the values for the variables used when Vbe = 0? Yes it is from an electronics course, but since there is a lot of plain mathematics involved I thought to ask here.

Comment: Yes but I don't know what $vBE$ is exactly, sorry.

Comment: I know what all of the terms and their underlying relations are, no worries. Just didn't understand the equation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it means we're evaluating the expression at $v_{BE} = 0$, in other words, plugging in $0$ for $v_{BE}$.

It's a bit odd that $v_{BE}$ doesn't show up in the formula, but it must depend on $v_{BE}$ somehow; perhaps one of the other variables depends on $v_{BE}$, that sort of thing.

This notation is common in a calculus course. It's not entirely uncommon to see something like

$$\frac{df}{dx}\Bigg|_{x = a}$$ to mean "take the derivative of $f$, and plug in $x = a,$" another way to write $f'(a)$.

The notation for a definite integral uses this kind of shorthand. When we have an antiderivative $F$ and write $F(x)\Big|_a^b$ to mean $F(b) - F(a)$, we "evaluate $F$ at $b$ and $a$" (and subtract, but the notation isn't identical here, just very similar).

Answer (score 1):

As an example:

Consider $R= \frac{10}{I} \big|_{I=2}$

All you do is $R=\frac{10}{2}=5$

Hope this helps.

As with any symbol you should be careful that no other meaning could be intended.